# Minecraft Forge mod - log in as player in development enviroment

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am developing a Minecraft mod with Forge, and I need to test it on a server. How do I log in with my Minecraft account so that I can join a server? The IDE I am using is Eclipse, and the workspace is set up using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmWBP5ifDlw) tutorial (standard forge setup).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer:

Go to run->run configurations...->Arguments and add two arguments as follows:

```
--username "my@email" --password "mypassword"
```

Comment: "The name you sent was invalid!"

Comment: I'm getting `Unknown command-line option '--username'.` on the `runClient` task

Comment: @xjcl that's odd, I'm afraid I don't really know how to do this anymore, it seems to have changed and I can't find the new behaviour in my (admittedly short) search

Comment: However, on older versions (I'm currently on 1.8.9) it still does work, so it's a valid answer there